# send mail without passwords

Tags: php, email, passwords, smtp-auth

Is there any way in php or javascript to send mail without passwords.
I need to send mail without asking for his passwords.
Please help me finding the solution.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

this the code i tried

```
<?php

 error_reporting(E_ALL);
$to = "person2@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "person2@gmail.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) or die("errors");
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

and it displays errors as o/p and not sending mail

Comment: What would you need passwords for?

Comment: Just don't write password in this email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PHP you can just use the `mail()` function, this does not require the user to enter his/her password.

The SMTP server can be set in `php.ini`.

Comment: i tried it but could not send the mail or i didnt even received failed message.

Comment: @krishna Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of your code and see if there's any error output.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer below link for this

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp

mail() function does not work on localhost so check this on server.